# perform ocr and rename on multiple files

Tags: tesseract-ocr

I have a folder of hundreds of images which contain a header with text. I want to extract the first line of text from each image using OCR, and rename the file to that text. Or if it's easier, put the text in the image metadata.

I have tesseract installed and I'm using zsh on MacOS.
What is the best way to accomplish this please?
Thanks.

Comment: [Python](https://www.python.org/) and the [pytesseract module](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) may be a good solution to this issue.

Comment: I don't know Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
mkdir renamed

for filename in *.jpg
do
text=$(tesseract "$filename" stdout | head -1)
cp "$filename" renamed/"$text".jpg
done
```

- `for filename in *.jpg` runs a loop through the files that match `*.jpg`;
- `text=$(tesseract "$filename" stdout | head -1)` executes `tesseract` on the file and pipes the text into the `head -1`, which outputs only the first line. The result goes to the variable `text`
- `cp "$filename" renamed/"$text".jpg` copies the file to directory `renamed` with the name `"$text".jpg`.

To eliminate any garbage read before the desired text, you can use `text=$(tesseract "$filename" stdout | grep -E ".{10}" | head -1)` instead. The command `grep -E ".{10}"` will eliminate any line with less than 10 characters.

If you are going to use the move or rename command, make a backup of the files first.

Comment: thank you for the script and _explaining_ each part! I will try it out.

Comment: It worked!  
I had to make a few changes though. I was using a UZN file to specify a text region (cts.uzn) and it needs to have the same file base name as the image.

#!/bin/zsh

#
# script to recognize text in image and rename file
#

mkdir ./renamed

for filename in *.jpg
do
cp "$filename" cts.jpg
text=$(tesseract --psm 4 cts.jpg stdout | head -1)
mv cts.jpg renamed/"$text".jpg
done